# Is it possible to make touchpad on Lenovo G780 disabled by default?

Tags: touchpad, lenovo-laptop

Fn+F6 works fine to disable touchpad on Lenovo G780. But when it wakes up from sleep, the touchpad is enabled again. Is there a way to make this disabling persist (without disabling the driver completely, since I *may* end up without a mouse sometime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Synaptics, ElanTECH driver normally has this functionality.  [Lenovo Synaptics ElanTech driver](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028121) is downloaded here for Windows.  This app appears in Control Panel once installed.  They have XP and Windows 8 drivers as well.

Comment: It showed up immediately after installation, but only worked after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click "ELAN Pointing Device" on the taskbar
2. Click "Property of Touch-Pad" then "ELAN"
3. Check "Disable when external USB pointing device plug in"
4. Apply and OK

Hope this helps! :D